# Searching MongoDB by the auto '_id' field, not possible?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to query MongoDB and find the row which has a specific '_id' but I can not do that. When I write for example:

```
$r = $cursor->getNext();
```

and debug, I find the value of $r['_id'] is empty. Not null, but empty! Any idea why this happens and how to avoid it? Using PHP

#### Update:

I was able to retrieve the '_id' by `$cursor->key()` but still I can't query and I wonder why the reason behind that!

Comment: Perhaps you want o provide the related code performing the query itself instead of throwing non-speaking snippets at us?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the '_id' by `$cursor->key()` but still I can't query and I wonder why the reason behind that!

Comment: If you want an answer to any question, you need to explain the problem better and also provide the code you're using.

Comment: You should **edit your question** and add this information there.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that the reason is that you are not using the [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) class.

Comment: That is the most common mistake -- people using a string and not the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful to avoid RDBMS thinking.  The ObjectID is not a primary key.  Bear in mind that MongoDB evolved as an answer to handle the problem posed by "Big Data".  This means lots and lots of data, possibly hundreds of thousands of entries each day ... you get the picture.  Accordingly, ObjectID represents a pseudo-random key which allows rapid inserting of data without having to find the RDBMS equivalent of "last insert ID".

If you are really keen to use _id as an equivalent to an RDBMS primary key, just overwrite it when inserting the document in the first case:

```
db.collection.insert({_id:100,name:"Joe",balance:200.18})
```

You could then easily find this document as follows:

```
db.collection.find({_id:100})
```

But you might start to run into scalability problems ... and then you're back to the problem of how do you determine which is the next key to generate.  Also, **_id** *must* be unique.  If you accidentally add a new document with the same **_id** as an existing document, you'll get a "duplicate key" error when using **insert()**.  If you add a document using **save()** and **_id** already exists, you'll end up overwriting the data on the existing document!

More thoughts later ...